# MAUI app reports "could not find android.jar for API level" XA5207 error

Tags: maui

When using Visual Studio 2022 to build a MAUI application targeting Android, you might see an error along the lines of "could not find android.jar for API level ##". The error message below shows for API version 31:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix that, go to Tools | Android | Android SDK Manager and inspect the dialog there:

[image]

What's a bit confusing to this dialog is that is you scan the Name column ("1", in the image), you'll see only references to API 32 and then Android 12, 11, etc. You might be looking for the SDK for the API Level 31 and you won't see it in the name... Instead, look at the API Level column ("2", in the image) and there you'll see the API Levels listed. The error message I saw indicated that the android.jar for API Level 31 was not found and that's because it's not checked. My job now is to check the "Android 12.0 - S" entry a click Apply Changes. After that, that missing SDK error should be resolved. If it isn't, check the path cited in the error message to ensure that the android.jar file is there. If it is, restart Visual Studio 2022. If it isn't then the SDK reinstall did not succeed and you should use the Android SDKs and Tools dialog to uninstall/reinstall the API Level SDK in question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so not exactly what the questions is asking for, but quite related.

First launched Visual Studio installer and ensured I selected the required DotNet MAUI workload.

[image: Ensure Workloads are installed in Visual Studio]

[image: Ensure Workloads are installed in Visual Studio]

Second I created a dotnet maui app from command line as follows.

```
dotnet new maui --name MauiCliBasic --framework net6.0
```

Now when I try to build with the following command,

```
cd MauiCliBasic
dotnet build ./MauiCliBasic.csproj
```

I got the following error.

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(533,2): error XA5207: Could not find android.jar for API level 31. This means the Android SDK platform for API level 31 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager...), or chan
> ge the Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar missing.) [C:\Tria
> ls\Ex\LearnMaui\src\apps\200500-MauiCliBasic\MauiCliBasic.csproj::TargetFramework=net6.0-android]

Its not clear whats happening, but when I ran the same solution using Visual Studio 2022 this time(not command line), things are clear.

I get the following error message.

[image: Running dotnet maui from Vs 2022]

[image: Error I get when Running dotnet maui app]

In a dialog titled **Enable Developer Mode for Windows**

I get the following message/error.

```
This device needs to be set up correctly to develop this type of app for Windows. 
If you don't then you can't install and test your app before you submit it to the Windows Store.

Go to settings for develops on your device, and select Developer Mode.

This device is not currently in developer Mode.
```

So go to the Windows Settings, click **For Developers** tab and switch on developer mode.

[image: Switch on developer mode on Windows Settings]

Its not over yet.

Install Android tools as follows.

[image: Install Android SDK 1]

[image: Install Android SDK 2]

[image: Install Android Emulator]

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered the same problem before, you can try to  repair your visual studio.

For more information ,you can check document: [Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).